# Unable to use HTML5 tags

Tags: spring, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, pom.xml

I can't use HTML5 tags in my Spring Boot project (tags like `strong` and `header`). Do I have to add anything else in my pom.xml to see my HTML rendered correctly?

Would you please look at this pom.xml and tell me the problem?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>springBootTestProject</groupId>
<artifactId>springBootTestProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the exact error being output?

Comment: there is no error in my code . it just writes simple code without <strong> <em> tags. It means I am not able to see HTML5 tags such like <strong> <em> <header> <section> <article>

Comment: how is your `ITemplateResolver` bean configuration? what template mode are you using? Guess you are running with default settings

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43584145/7226417

Comment: all the answers  are true. But the problem is whne I use <head> tags outside the <body> tag HTML5 tags are not visible. When I use head tags outside <body> tag I can see the HTML5 tags withoyut any problem. how <head> tags are related to this problem?